# How do I re-size and place multiple images into a frame template Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Frame template png.

[image]

All images are saved as .png. I have been copying the frame template dragging the image onto the frame > Transform > Scale > dragging layer below the frame > merging layers > saving for web > 
below is the frame. To do this for each image is a bit time consuming. If I create an action to do this I am not sure if it will work due to the fact each original is of a different size. 
 What I would like to ask is what is the best time saving way to do this? Batch automation or other(instructions of the path I should take)

Comment: The starting point is different, but otherwise, this is quite similar: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120379/i-need-to-create-60-unique-framed-mirrors-for-product-images-looking-for-a-way

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *frame.psd* file with a *Background* layer and the *FRAME* layer, you can record and play the following action to each image:

[image]

- Menu File → Automate → Fit image: the width and height bigger than the inner frame (≈ 10/20 pixels)
- Select All
- Copy
- Close without saving
- Select the *background* layer
- Paste
- Save

[image: ani]

Comment: Thankyou Danielillo , I will give this a go

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if it will work due to the fact each original is of a
>   different size.

I think this is probably the main barrier to full automation. Obviously, automated resizing/cropping of the images to the same aspect ratio may not work for all images. So, perhaps a way to speed up manual resizing/cropping would help you, so you could then just record an Action in Photoshop to automate the rest of the work.

When I have hundreds of photos to crop manually, I use Lightroom.  There's no saving required after each edit, so you can simply concentrate on making the crops. You can set the crop to a predefined aspect ratio. When finished, in Lightroom you can export all the cropped images to a specific size in one go.

Comment: Thankyou Billy, I had lightroom and will install again  I think I shall first try the action option that Danielillo suggested below.